# Problems searching and joining network with Nexus One

Tags: nexus-one, htc, sim-card, networking

I have a Nexus One, unlocked from Google. It is not rooted nor running custom firmware. I am trying to use it with 2 different international sim cards, which have worked in other peoples phones. I have tried in four different countries, in all cases I get an error unable to search for networks.

Android version is 2.3.6

How can I troubleshoot and hopefully fix this?

Comment: "unable to search for networks" is not an error I'm familiar with. Can you provide the exact error text and more info about when you see it?